# InvalidAuthenticityToken issue when calling ajax from assets/javascript/ function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a link like `<a href="" onclick=" return del_file(<%= "#{file.id}" %>)">Delete</a>` this function `del_file` is defined in `assets/javascript/file.js` it calls an `ajax` and deletes file from server . this has been working for past 8 months. this week i have gone through some major changes in front end but the `InvalidAuthenticityToken` keeps showing in `logs` while i've not touched the backend code a bit. can anyone tell why it has changed its behavior. i'm using `rails 4.2` and `ruby 2.3.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include the CSRF token before sending the request, which is taken from the meta attribute. If you're using jQuery $.ajax, you'll have to add this in the options object:

```
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
},
```

Alternatively, you could use the *remote: true* tag to create a rails ajax request, which will handle the CSRF token submission.

Comment: it worked well but why it was working before ???? i was not using any beforesend method alongside ajax for token